# Can you have multiple IN conditions in a PowerShell ForEach loop?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, hashtable

I have the following sample code in a function:

```
[array]$ARR = $null

foreach ($file in $fileTable.identical)
{
   [hashtable]$HT=@{
       'FileName' = $file.Name
       'AppName' = $file.App
       'GroupName' = $file.Group
       'Valid' = $true
   }
   $ARR += $HT
}
foreach ($file in $fileTable.removed)
{
   [hashtable]$HT=@{
       'FileName' = $file.Name
       'AppName' = $file.App
       'GroupName' = $file.Group
       'Valid' = $false
   }
   $ARR += $HT
}
foreach ($file in $fileTable.modified)
{
   [hashtable]$HT=@{
       'FileName' = $file.Name
       'AppName' = $file.App
       'GroupName' = $file.Group
       'Valid' = $false
   }
   $ARR += $HT
}

return $ARR
```

+3 more foreach loops for other $fileTable.[properties] where 'Valid' = $false as well.

Instead of having to repeat the block of code multiple times, I want to do something like:

```
foreach (($file in $fileTable.removed) -and ($file in $fileTable.modified))
{
   [hashtable]$HT=@{
       'FileName' = $file.Name
       'AppName' = $file.App
       'GroupName' = $file.Group
       'Valid' = $false
   }
}
```

So only variable different in the hashtable will be $value.
$fileTable is a pscustomobject with a few custom properties like identical, modified, added, removed.

I know what I want is not possible in foreach loops but I'm looking for a similar solution to reduce the number of lines of code. Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: `$ARR = @('identical', 'removed', 'modified' | % { $fileTable.$_ } | % { @{ 'FileName' = $_.Name; 'AppName' = $_.App; 'GroupName' = $_.Group; 'Valid' = $false } })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining your and [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)s approaches.

**Edit: incorporated [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)s hint**

```
$ARR = foreach($Variant in 'identical', 'removed', 'modified'){
  $fileTable.$Variant | ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      'FileName'  = $_.Name
      'AppName'   = $_.App
      'GroupName' = $_.Group
    # 'Valid'     = if($Variant -eq 'identical'){$True} else {$False}
      'Valid'     = $Variant -eq 'identical'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, but `'Valid'     = $Variant -eq 'identical'` should do.